# Pointing servers to a new Chef organization

Tags: automation, chef-infra, devops

I have a set of VMs that were previously connected to a Chef account which has now been closed.  What would I have to change in order to have my current servers connect to a different chef organization and be able to run properly again?

Answer (score 0):

with knife bootstrap command

for more read [this page](https://docs.chef.io/knife_bootstrap.html)

Comment: This won't remove the actual client.pem key, and so won't help register the node to the new org unless you're talking about validatorless bootstrap.

Answer (score 0):

I'll try to give all options as you're not telling much on the VM (OS), chef-client version nor kind of account you have on hosted chef:

1. First case, if there's no backup of your nodes object you can reinject in your new org
   :

   There's not much solutions there, you'll have to update the client.rb file to point chef_server_url to your new org, replace the validator.pem file and remove the client.pem file to let the node register itself in the new org.

   You'll lose all the runlist, probably environment settings too.
2. Second case, you have a backup of your nodes object as json files, as oles and environments too.

   In this case you can upload all this to your new organization and the only change you'll have to do on nodes will be to update the client.rb on all nodes to update the chef_server_url entry. (using `sed` for example on linux)
3. Side note:

   As you're on hosted Chef, you can open a ticket at `https://support.chef.io` to ask them if they are able to send you a backup of your previous organization too, I can't tell if it will be free of charge or not.